# saving content from textarea in php

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

i have a textarea in a php page and and i want to save it on click of save button. but i have the insert queries in another php page. how shall i save the content without page refresh.
my immediate thought was ajax. but is it safe to transfer content through javascript or should i use session variables to carry the whole text content
 help me in it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use AJAX. Make sure you use a `POST` request as the text may be too long to be sent by `GET` (that is, appended to the URL in a query string).

Sessions are not a valid option. Sessions are files that exist on the server. In order to put the contents of a textarea into a session, you first have to get it to the server, so it's not a solution to the problem of getting the text to the server.

Answer (score 1):

i think the ajax is the best solution,

make in your server side (php) sanity before insert to db (like [mysql_real_escape_string](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php))

Answer (score 0):

Session variables are only stored on the server, so they cannot be used to transfer data from the client to the server. I you want to submit data without having the user to reload the page, ajax is the way to go.